# codeigniter controller not being called due to directory with same name

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, controller, directory

I would like to avoid renaming directories or method names if at all possible, this was working on a previous server before being moved to a new hosting.

My directory structure is as follows:

- /magazine
- /site
- /site/config
- /site/config/routes.php (routes contains entry: $route["magazine"] = "site/magazine")
- /site/controllers
- /site/controllers/site.php (site controller contains method "magazine")
- /site/models
- /site/views
- /.htaccess
- /index.php

Everything about the site works perfectly until I browse to /magazine, and it tries to go to magazine directory, when I need it to goto the magazine method within the site controller.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Not able to understand your question, can you elaborate last sentence.

Comment: When I use my web browser to visit mydomain.com/magazine, its going to the actualy magazine directory instead of the magazine method within my site controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess file you probably have something like looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Try adding an additional rule for "magazine":

```
RewriteRule ^magazine/?$ index.php/magazine [L]
```

Comment: Yes I have what you suggested, though without the check for the directory. Do I need another RewriteCond specifically for magazine?

Comment: @MikeJouwstra YOu should't need any conditions for that because it *is* a directory, except you want it to be routed through index.php